# Asp.Net MVC: How to add information at the end of a page's url, in the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I'm working on an asp.net mvc application and I need to modify the url that is in the browser, adding a "/something-more-here". The fact is that I have article content that is rendered on a page, but currently the url looks like this: https://localhost:44328/Blog/Article.
And it needs to be like this: https://localhost:44328/Blog/Article/article-name.
How can I do this url customization?

Comment: Probably `RedirectToAction` but there are a few other choices, here's a simple explanation https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/return-view-vs-return-redirecttoaction-vs-return-redirect-vs-return-redirecttoroute

Answer (score 0):

you can use this on html

```
<a href="/ControllerName/ActionMethodName">....</a>
```

You can also use this if you want to redirect via controller

```
return RediretToAction("ActionName","ControllerName");
```